# Render inline HTML to an Image in VB.Net

Tags: html, vb.net, image, converters, content-type

Basically I have a string that will looks like this :

```
<p>HELLO <span style='color:red'>WORLD</span></p>
```

How would I go about converting this *string* of HTML into an image? (Bitmap, PNG, etc.)

Does anyone know of any VB.NET tools that will do this? Since this is a string, it cannot read from the DOM as it technically isn't part of the DOM.

My overall purpose is to create an ASPX page that will reading a field containing some HTML from a database, converting that HTML into an image, and the steaming that image on the page by spoofing the ContentType to "image/png", thereby creating a dynamic image that I can use in an RDLC file.

The reason we're displaying HTML as an image in an RDLC file is simply because all of our reports are using ReportViewer version 9.0 which does not support interpreted HTML. Creating a dynamic image based on HTML allows us to display the "formatting" that we want to show directly in the report, which we could not do otherwise, not with such flexibility anyways.

Comment: You mean without writing your own HTML parser? Have you thought about automating a browser and taking a screenshot?

Comment: Interesting, I unfortunately haven't touched the WebBrowser class, could you expand on that a little more! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can render html on the screen using the WebBrowser control, then copy the screen bitmap to am image file.

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<p>HELLO <span style='color:red'>WORLD</span></p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code ALMOST works. You need to click the button twice, and it only works properly on the second click. There is a timing issue with grabbing the rendered page you will need to solve. Also, the form must be in front, as it is a screengrab, so only grabs the visible portion of the screen.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strHTML As String = "<p>HELLO <span style='color:red'>WORLD</span></p>"
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = strHTML
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = GetControlImage(WebBrowser1)
    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.png"
    bmp.Save(strFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
  End Sub

  Private Declare Function BitBlt _
    Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdcDest As IntPtr, _
    ByVal x As Int32, _
    ByVal y As Int32, _
    ByVal Width As Int32, _
    ByVal Height As Int32, _
    ByVal hdcSrc As IntPtr, _
    ByVal xSrc As Int32, _
    ByVal ySrc As Int32, _
    ByVal dwRop As Int32 _
    ) As Boolean
  Private Const SRCCOPY As Integer = &HCC0020

  Function GetControlImage(ctl As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim grpInput As Graphics = ctl.CreateGraphics
    ' Create a compatible bitmap and get its Graphics object
    Dim bmpOutput As New Bitmap(ctl.ClientRectangle.Width, ctl.ClientRectangle.Height, grpInput) 'formImage = New Bitmap(frmForm.ClientRectangle.Width, frmForm.ClientRectangle.Height, formGraphics)
    Dim grpOutput As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOutput)

    ' Get the target and source device context handles (hDC)
    Dim sourceDC As IntPtr = grpInput.GetHdc
    Dim targetDC As IntPtr = grpOutput.GetHdc

    ' Copy the control's client area
    BitBlt(targetDC, 0, 0, ctl.ClientRectangle.Width, ctl.ClientRectangle.Height, sourceDC, ctl.ClientRectangle.X, ctl.ClientRectangle.Y, SRCCOPY)

    ' Release DCs and dispose objects
    grpInput.ReleaseHdc(sourceDC)
    grpInput.Dispose()
    grpOutput.ReleaseHdc(targetDC)
    grpOutput.Dispose()
    Return bmpOutput
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, regrettably I need to include a reference to System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization which doesn't seem to be supported in .Net 2.0 from what I can see

Comment: I just checked, and it should work with .NET 2.0
I created a new .NET 2.0 Windows forms app in VS2012, added a webbrowser control and a button control to the form, then cut-paste the code above. Single-clicking the button twice generated the image file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf also has a a wkhtmltoimage.exe that you can utilize, try http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

Adding "`Application.DoEvents`" immediately before the instruction "`Dim bmp As Bitmap = GetControlImage(WebBrowser1)`" seems to solve the problem of having to press the button twice.